# Algorithms that must compute a global property?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request

Could you give me examples of polynomial-time algorithms that must compute a global property over their entire input? A purely illustrative example of this might be a graph algorithm that somehow must count the total number of nodes before computing its final answer.

Comment: Finding the minimum element of an array or a list?

Answer (score 1):

A silly example: Checking if a graph has more than m nodes. :-)

Some more interesting examples:

- Checking if a graph is connected.
- Checking if a graph has an Eulerian cycle. A graph is Eulerian iff all degrees are even and the graph is connected: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path
- Checking if a graph has a perfect matching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm